# Is this the optimal way to write "find these IDs in a list of objects" using linq?

Tags: c#, optimization, linq

I've got a situation where I have a list of `Organization`s (code to follow), and a user has a list of OrganizationIds (`int`s). I want to filter down the full list of Organizations using the User's OrganizationId list for a dropdown list. The query works, but it feels like there may be a more optimal way to write it. Is there, or am I already pretty much optimized?

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Query

```
vm.locations = _organizations.GetOrganizations().Where(o => ((ApplicationUser)User).OrganizationIdList.Any(u => u == o.Id)).Select(org =>
    new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = org.Division + " - " + org.Name,
        Value = org.Id.ToString()
    }).OrderBy(item => item.Text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<int, Organization>` to look up organizations by their IDs quickly.

Your code will then look like this: `OrganizationIdList.Select(id => organizations[id])...`.

---

Given your clarification in the comments that your are getting organizations from a database, you should let the database do the hard work for you. The code will depend upon the ORM you're using, but a relatively SQL-agnostic version of the query will look like this:

```
SELECT organization_id, division, name FROM organizations WHERE organization_id IN (?)
```

or this:

```
SELECT organization_id, division, name FROM organizations JOIN user_organizations
USING (organization_id) WHERE user_id = ?
```

Comment: `GetOrganizations()` returns a `List<Organization>` -- wouldn't the conversion to a `Dictionary` be more intensive? (I agree this is clearer and cleaner, though!)

Comment: @pennstatephil can you change `GetOrganizations`? Do the organizations change over time? Are they coming from a database? It's hard to recommend what to do without more context.

Comment: they are indeed coming from a DB. while changes are not likely to happen often, they can occur.

Comment: @pennstatephil then you should let the db do the work for you. Either select from organizations where organization_id in ... Or select from organizations join users using organization_id where user_id = ...